# How long does it take to get confirmation?

Tags: mac, ios, developer-program

I am an iOS developer and I just enrolled in the mac developer program. The site says i'll get confirmation in 24 hours, what is the 'normal' time in which confirmation is usually received?

Comment: Was about 12 hours for me.

Comment: @calum wow that was a quick reply lol thnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends. It can take a few hours for a personal enrollment to several days for a company enrollment. If you want your company name (rather than your personal name) to show up on your apps, you'll need to take the extra time to confirm.

I also suspect that during times of peak enrollment (say after an announcement like at WWDC) that the confirmation takes longer simply due to the number of people applying to play with the beta.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/support/ios/purchase-and-next-steps.html#purchasecomplete has a nice timeline of what happens after you pay and before it is confirmed and active in the system.